# Passing string parameter into constructor to call function

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

I have come across this programming style where:
Instead of calling an object method directly, they pass in its constructor method a string, the constructor method then check this string and call the function associate with it.

```
function MySimpleObject(option){
  if (typeof option === 'String'){
    pluginMethods[String].apply(this, arguments);
  }
  else {
    init();
  }
}
```

This seem to be used with jQuery as extend function a lot.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({simpleObj: MySimpleObject});
```

I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me on this.

Comment: Which part are you not sure about? And shouldn't your code snippet there be `pluginMethods[option].apply(this, arguments);`?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows the following style of programming, which is used by jQuery UI for example:

```
$('selector').datepicker('option', 'option-name', 'option-value');
```

If you call `.datepicker()` with no arguments or an object, it initializes the datepicker. When the first argument is a string, it's a call to a method of the datepicker. This approach is used for all the jQuery UI widgets, and is common among many other jQuery plugins as well.